Sources for Raba bar bar Hana legends explanations
Are there any sources and books that explains Raba bar bar Hana legends in Kabbalistic and Pshat perspective?

As with any Aggadaic portion, Chiddushei Agaddos of Maharsha, printed at the back of the Gemara, is the first place to start. You will also find a wealth of depth in the Chiddushei Agaddos of Maharal m'Prague, or Ben Yehoyada (by the Ben Ish Chai).
The Vilna Gaon wrote extensively on these Aggados. An entire volume 'ביאור על אגדות' is dedicated to these few pages of Baba Basra.
IIRC, Likutei Maharan (R' Nachman Breslov) contains a section explaining these aggados.
R' Ahron Feldman authored a book 'The River, The Kettle and The Bird', a Torah guide to marriage based on the writings of the Vilna Gaon on this gemara.
A great resource for sources on Aggada is the contemporary collection Leket Pirushei Agadda (link is to Baba Basra 73), by R' Tzuriel, which refers to many other sefarim who discuss these gemaros.

If I recall, R' Feldman's book The Juggler and the King is devoted in significant part to this topic.

Ben yehoyada is by the Ben Ish chai. Maybe you meant ot write ".. in the chidddushei agados of the maharal miprague, and the Ben yehoyada... "

I think R' Kook goes through them as well in Maamarei Raayah but I don't own it so I can't actually check.

Has anybody read this book: The Tales of Rabbah bar bar Hannah by Eisenstein, Judah David? (https://hebrewbooks.org/2696)

Has anybody read this book: מעשה רב - פירוש על מאמרי רבה בר בר חנה בדרך פרד"ס / ר' משה בנימין מבבל (https://hebrewbooks.org/19636)?

There is also an edition of Rabbi Abraham Isaac Hakohen Kook "The Legends of Rabbah Bar Bar Hannah" translated by R. Betzlel Naor.
Also as the comment notes, R. Aharon Feldman's "The Juggler and the King".

In honour of Daf HaYomi reaching the Rabba bar bar Hana aggadata, Artscroll has released [and kindly distributed freely] their own compilation on the above aggadata, with Artscroll's standard translation, commentary and notes.
You can download it here1

1. I take no responsibility for any violation of copyright laws. Supposedly, Artscroll distributed this freely; I received this from a trustworthy source.  

For a p'shat perspective, you can check out Mendel Wohlman's מסתרי האגדה, vol. 1, p. 95 and onwards (available on Otzar Hachochmah). He emphasized identifying the historical and geographical reality behind the stories, and separating the parables from descriptions of real occurrences. Be aware that it's a fairly old book, so it's based on information known in the early 20th century.
